# SourceTree Open in Terminal error: mintty.exe Entry Point Not Found

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I found myself using the Terminal in SourceTree a lot recently on my office pc. When I got home however, I noticed this does not work on my laptop, the error I receive is the following:

[image: Error]

I have tried googling the problem and reinstalling git and SourceTree, with no results.

Comment: Slightly obtuse answer but, Use [git extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) instead, sourcetree (IMO) is a horrible product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem, if not the same. Found that Sourcetree (or some older version of Sourcetree) includes a portable version of git (that comes with its own shell). In my case that version was from 2015. I expect an upgrade elsewhere on my system or a PATH variable ordering problem caused some kind of DLL hell.

My solution:

1. First install a [more official](https://git-scm.com/) git package.
2. Open SourceTree, then go to the SourceTree Options dialog and 
   navigate to the Git tab.
3. Inside groupbox "Git Version", click the button "Use System Git".

Now SourceTree would use the official git instead of the built-in portable stuff. There is now a chance your terminal button works again.

Comment: Even though I have switched to using GitKraken now, I tried your solution and it fixes my SourceTree, thank you! Hope it proves useful to someone in the future.